# Como llamar a una variable desde template django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto: Al momento de iniciar sesión necesito obtener el nombre del laboratorio al cual estoy ingresando. Mi modelo laboratorio es:

```
class Lab_nombre(models.Model):
     nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     telefono = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     propietario = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     ruc = models.CharField(max_length=15)
     estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Tengo otro modelo llamado Profile el cual liga el usuario y el laboratorio:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, null= False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab_nombre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

En mi template index.html deseo poner el nombre del laboratorio al cual pertenece ese usuario centrado en la parte superior, algo como lo que hago con el nombre de usuario que se logea:

```
 {{request.user.username}}
```

Al momento de iniciar session se redirecciona a la ulr:

```
r = redirect(reverse('laboratorio:consultar_ordenes'))
```

Mi vista consultar_ordenes:

```
@login_required
def busqueda_ordenes(request):
    c_orden = None
try:
    user = request.user
    perfil =  Profile.objects.get(user_id = user.id)
    pacientes = OrdenPaciente.objects.filter(perfil_id = perfil.id).order_by('-id')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'q' in request.GET:
          #  form = BuscarForm(request.GET)
            q = request.GET['q'].split()
            for param in q:
                pacientes = OrdenPaciente.objects.filter((
                    Q(paciente__apellidos__icontains=param) | Q(paciente__numero_identificacion__icontains=param) | Q(
                        paciente__nombres__icontains=param)| Q(
                        id__icontains=param) | Q(doctor__nombres__icontains=param)|
                    Q(doctor__apellidos__icontains=param)),perfil_id=perfil.id).order_by('-id')



#  page = request.GET.get('page')
    object_listt = pacientes
    paginator = Paginator(object_listt, 20)  #

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    c_orden = paginator.get_page(page)
   # print(pacientes_list)

except:
    pass
    #print(object_list)
return render(request, 'consultar_ordenes.html',
              {"page_title": u"Consultar Ordenes", "c_orden": c_orden})
```

Como lo podría hacer para poner el nombre del laboratorio?, alguien que pueda ayudarme.

Comment: podrias mandar como context desde el views hacia el template haciendo un query con el usuario

Comment: profile=Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.pk)....profile.nombre..y ese nombre mandarias a tu template

Comment: Gracias @DiegoAvila, lo que sucede es que no se como enviarle al index.html ya que al momento iniciar sesión hago un redirect  r = redirect(reverse('laboratorio:consultar_ordenes'), el cual carga un template el cual a su vez carga el index y base_view.html que son los html bases: {% extends "base_view.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

Comment: como tienes tu view consultar_ordenes agrega tu codgo en la pregunta

Comment: editala la pregunta "https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/240970/edit"

Comment: ok listo @DiegoAvila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roberto, si ya tienes el modelo `Profile` asociado a tu usuario y asumiendo que todos tus usuarios tengan un perfil, solo tienes que usar esa relación existente para llegar hasta el laboratorio.

En tu template podrías usar esto:

```
{{request.user.profile.lab.nombre}}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Cesar, en el modelo usuario no tengo como foreing key el profile, solo en el modelo Profile asocio el user y laboratorio, no se si estoy en lo correcto pero no creo podría hacer: {{request.user.profile.lab.nombre}}. Existe alguna manera de hacer {{request.profile.lab.nombre}} o de pronto {{request.lab.nombre}}?

Comment: @RobertoFeijoo no entiendo a qué te refieres. En tu modelo `Profile` has definido una relación uno a uno con el usuario. Sí puedes hacer lo que yo he planteado.

Comment: Cesar, si es verdad lo que tu dices, me estaba complicando la vida. Muy bien una vez más agradezco tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

en tu vista ya tienes el query que se necesita tan solo deberias pasarlo como context algo asi:
Query:

```
perfil =  Profile.objects.get(user_id = user.id)
```

en tu context:

```
return render(request, 'consultar_ordenes.html',
              {"page_title": u"Consultar Ordenes", "c_orden": c_orden, 'perfil_usuario':perfil.nombre})
```

si te fijas he agregado **perfil_usuario**, el mismo sera accedido con:

```
{{ perfil_usuario }}
```

desde tu template, espero te ayude y suerte..!!